# TypeScript: Infer specific types of arguments and return values of functions in a mapped object

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build a type-protected interface to my module.

A simplified version would be like this:

```js
const userResult = myFunc({
  foo: (key, arg) => {
    // users do something here with:
    //   - key inferred as "foo" and
    //   - arg inferred as string
    return "foobar";
  },
  bar: (key, arg) => {
    // users do something here with:
    //   - key inferred as "bar" and
    //   - arg inferred as number
    return 1;
  },
})
```

Here `myFunc` is the interface function to my module. Users can pass an object with arbitrary keys (`foo` and `bar` in the example) and functions of a specific type whose arguments are `key` and `arg` and the return value is a string (`"foobar"` in the example) or a number (`1` in the example).

My goal is to infer the type of `arg` as the same type as the return value of a function, while setting the type of `key` as a string literal identical to the key of an entry.

I've been struggling with this for a long but I have managed to find this working almost perfectly:

```js
type Value = string | number;
type MyType<K, T extends Value> = (key: K, arg: T) => T;

function myFunc<
  Ks extends keyof R,
  R extends { [K in Ks]: MyType<K, Value> },
>(
  userObj: {
    [K in Ks]: R[K];
  },
) {
  // do some complicated staffs
}
```

The resulted type inference by TypeScript for the example user input is:

```
function myFunc<"foo" | "boo", {
    foo: (key: "foo", arg: Value) => string;
    boo: (key: "boo", arg: Value) => number;
}>(userObj: {
    foo: (key: "foo", arg: Value) => string;
    boo: (key: "boo", arg: Value) => number;
}): ResultType // whatever type we return
```

The last missing point is that `arg` is inferred as Value, not as a specific type (string for `foo` and number for `boo`.)

Is there any solution to this?
Any hint or comment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the arg type for each key should always be the same, defining a mapping type can be useful and then deriving your types from that. In this case, `ParamValues` is an object type and we'll use the type of each property to correspond to the type of the function arg and return value:

```
function myFunc<ParamValues>(userObj: {
  [K in keyof ParamValues]: (key: K, arg: ParamValues[K]) => ParamValues[K];
}) {
  // do something here
}

// Explicitly define the arg types per key
type SpecificValues = {
  foo: string,
  bar: number
}

myFunc<SpecificValues>({
  foo: (key, arg) => "Wa",
  bar: (key, arg) => arg + 1
})

// These fail because the operations being done on arg are not 
// supported by the value types from `SpecificValues`
myFunc<SpecificValues>({
  // @ts-expect-error
  foo: (key, arg) => arg * 3,
  // @ts-expect-error
  bar: (key, arg) => arg.slice(3),
  // @ts-expect-error
  baz: (key, arg) => arg + arg;
})
```

Or you could use type inference, but at some point you'll have to tell the compiler what your types are:

```
// This implies myFunc<{ blah: number, blag: string }>
myFunc({
  blah: (key, arg: number) => 4,
  blag: (key, arg: string) => "Woohoo!"
})

// This fails because return values do not match the arg types
myFunc({
  // @ts-expect-error
  blah: (key, arg: number) => "Yarg",
  // @ts-expect-error
  blag: (key, arg: string) => 3
})
```

In short, our `ParamValues` type isn't a type that any variables ever actually have; it's just a way to define a mapping of keys to types.

Comment: Thank you so much for an answer!

You mean there's no way to achieve it only by type inference, right? 
Then I will definitely consider the approaches you suggested.

But there are some concerns with each approach in my case. As fo the first one, I have to let users use arbitrary numbers and combination of keys and corresponding types of `arg`. I may require users to define types like `SpecificValues` for their own inputs, but I hesitate to force them (and myself as an user) to do it for UX since `arg` is not always important for every key.

Comment: And as for the second one, the actual version of `MyType` takes more arguments than the exampled version, so I put them into an object so that users can omit unnecessary ones. In that case, type annotations are annoying to write.